# GTK theme doesn't works on every window

Tags: xfce, gtk, xfce4, gtk3

I'm using Xubuntu and downloaded a GTK 3 theme. However, this theme does not affect all parts of XFCE. For example, the buttons of the "Appearance" window in the picture and the buttons and appearance of the "Software" window are different. How can I solve this?

[image: Theme]

Comment: Some apps don't respect themes.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: For a theme for all types you need one that does gtk2+gtk3+qt, but still some apps will ignore it.

Comment: OK, thank you @harrymc

Comment: As you have a solution, please uncouple the solution from the question, post it as an answer and mark it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem from `Settings Manager > Window Manager > Style > Theme`

[image: Solution]